# Binding Template to Skin

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

Hi I have a template a quote box template, I have set certain text colors for this template to match a certain skin. Is there a way to 'bind' templates to skins meaning one template will take effect using one skin a different version of the template for another. My wiki has a mobile skin and a desktop skin, the issue arising from thus.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up hard coding into the two separate templates, using a sprinkle of PHP to define a different quote on certain unique pages. Definitely not the most effective but hey, got the job done.

Now for some white knight moderator to ride past on his trusty steed and close this post, to localized perhaps? lol